# Fastest way of averaging multiple list of different length in Python

Tags: python, mongodb

So I have some list with pre calculated values (average of price of products by store) coming from Mongo. Each list represent a week with the different products. The lists can be of different size because sometimes a product is not sold during one week. The sublist of average by store can also be of different size in between two different weeks because some store can be out of stock (and therefore not have any price for this product).

Is there a way to obtain my Result without making many for loops ?

Here is an example with two weeks for clarification :

Week1

```
[{u'_id': 193390, u'avgT': 12, u'avgByS': [{u'S': 7, u'avg': 12}]}, {u'_id': 193396, u'avgT': 29, u'avgByS': [{u'S': 7, u'avg': 29}, {u'S': 5, u'avg': 29}]}]
```

Week2

```
[{u'_id': 193390, u'avgT': 11, u'avgByS': [{u'S': 7, u'avg': 10}, {u'S': 9, u'avg': 12}]}, {u'_id': 193398, u'avgT': 15, u'avgByS': [{u'S': 7, u'avg': 29}, {u'S': 5, u'avg': 29}]},{u'_id': 193396, u'avgT': 29, u'avgByS': [{u'S': 7, u'avg': 29}, {u'S': 5, u'avg': 29}]}]
```

Desired Output

```
[{u'_id': 193390, u'avgT': 11.5, u'avgByS': [{u'S': 7, u'avg': 11}, {u'S': 9, u'avg': 12}]}, {u'_id': 193398, u'avgT': 15, u'avgByS': [{u'S': 7, u'avg': 29}, {u'S': 5, u'avg': 29}]},{u'_id': 193396, u'avgT': 29, u'avgByS': [{u'S': 7, u'average': 29}, {u'S': 5, u'average': 29}]}]
```

Comment: What do you want to average from the lists? The length won't matter if you only care about one specific value. Besides, what's wrong with a for loop?

Comment: If the product is present in both week (the '_id' is present in both list), I need to average the average of price (the 'avg') if the are coming from the same store (= if the have the same 'avgByS.S‘). If for one product I have a price for two stores during one week and for one store during the second week (and that this one store was also in the previous week), this price is averaged over the two weeks. The other one is kept as is (not divided by 2 in this example).

Comment: The problems with for loop is that I have hundred of thousands of products and the final calculation won't be necessarily on two weeks but could range from one week to many (most likely under 52/53 which is equal to one year). And therefore it is slow with many imbricated for loops

Comment: Is 3 levels nested too much? If not I may have an example for you.

Comment: It should be fine. He who can do more can do less (Dunno if this proverb exists in English)

Comment: I think your question title just shot your here. And you probably just want the MongoDB aggregation framework operator [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/). You probably did to get to that point, but failed to understand how to simply get the average from what ended up in the list.

Comment: Thanks Nail, but what you see in my examples are already the results of an aggregation in mongodb. I don't want to store the results of every week calculation (with an $out for example) in mongodb and redo some aggregation on it. So I guess I will try the answer @robᵩ when I have some time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to obtain my Result without making many for loops ?

No. Your data structure is lists-within-lists. One cannot iterate the data without ... iteration.

But nested for loops are not always a bad idea! Some nested for loops result in O(N^2) behavior, but some nested for loops result in O(N) behavior, it depends upon your actual code.

Here is one way to compute your data. Note that it has three nested for loops. You can't avoid that. But none of the nested loops result in polynomial complexity. I'm rusty on big-O, but I claim the aggregation loop in the following program runs in O(N), where N is the total number of values in the `avgByS` lists. (The second loop's complexity would be equal to the first, but I call `sorted()` on the results. That may slow it down some.)

```
from __future__ import division
from pprint import pprint

weeks = [
    [{u'_id': 193390, u'avgT': 12, u'avgByS': [{u'S': 7, u'avg': 12}]}, {u'_id': 193396, u'avgT': 29, u'avgByS': [{u'S': 7, u'avg': 29}, {u'S': 5, u'avg': 29}]}],
    [{u'_id': 193390, u'avgT': 11, u'avgByS': [{u'S': 7, u'avg': 10}, {u'S': 9, u'avg': 12}]}, {u'_id': 193398, u'avgT': 15, u'avgByS': [{u'S': 7, u'avg': 29}, {u'S': 5, u'avg': 29}]},{u'_id': 193396, u'avgT': 29, u'avgByS': [{u'S': 7, u'avg': 29}, {u'S': 5, u'avg': 29}]}]
]

# First, accumlate the data. Convert lists to dicts.
total = {}
for week in weeks:
    for product in week:
        total_product = total.setdefault(
            product['_id'],
            {
                u'_id':product['_id'],
                u'avgT':[],
                u'avgByS':{}
            })
        total_product['avgT'].append(product['avgT'])
        for store in product['avgByS']:
            total_product['avgByS'].setdefault(store['S'],[]).append(store['avg'])
pprint (total)

# Next, convert dicts to lists and compute averages.
averages = [{
    u'_id': k,
    u'avgT': sum(v['avgT'])/len(v['avgT']),
    u'avgByS': [{
        u'S': kk,
        u'avg': sum(vv)/len(vv),
        }
        for kk,vv in sorted(v['avgByS'].items())]
    }
    for k,v in sorted(total.items())]
pprint(averages)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it as soon as I find some time. I'll mark it as accepted meanwhile (as I don't know when I can check it).